# How to convert this curl command in golang

Tags: linux, go, curl, https, tls1.2

```
curl --cert ./clientcert.pem --cert-type PEM --key ./clientkey.pem --cert-type PEM --cacert ./cacerts.pem --from "files=@test.xml" "https://example.com"
```

How to convert this curl command in golang? My code looks like this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "crypto/tls"
    "crypto/x509"
    "flag"
    "bytes"
)


func main() {


    xml_temp = "./test.xml"
    key_dir = "./clientkey.pem"
    cert_dir = "./clientcert.pem"
    cacert_dir = "./cacerts.pem"


    fmt.Println("loading ",*xml_temp)
    fmt.Println("loading ",*cert_dir)
    fmt.Println("loading ",*key_dir)
    fmt.Println("loading ",*cacert_dir)

    pool := x509.NewCertPool()

    caCrt, err := ioutil.ReadFile(*cacert_dir)
    if err != nil {
        panic("Unable to read caCert")
    }

    pool.AppendCertsFromPEM(caCrt)


    certFile, err := ioutil.ReadFile(*cert_dir)
    if err != nil {
        panic("Unable to read certPem")
    }

    keyFile, err := ioutil.ReadFile(*key_dir)
    if err != nil {
        panic("Unable to read keyPem")
    }

    fmt.Println("signing", *xml_temp, "...")

    cert, err := tls.X509KeyPair(certFile, keyFile)
    if err != nil {
        panic("Unable to read privateKey")
    }
    cfg := &tls.Config{Certificates: []tls.Certificate{cert}}

    client := &http.Client{
        Transport: &http.Transport{
            TLSClientConfig: cfg,
        },
    }

    url := "https://example.com"
    xml_body,err := ioutil.ReadFile(*xml_temp)
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, bytes.NewBuffer([]byte(xml_body)))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    defer resp.Body.Close()
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    fmt.Println(string(body))
}
```

why this doesn't work. I always get the error

> Your request does not contain a valid security token.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Hey,
If you have clientcert and clientkey in a file, I will suggest to use : tls.LoadX509KeyPair(./clientcert.pem, ./clientkey.pem) and this will return the cert directly to you. This will also outsource all the ioutils.ReadFile which you are doing. Can you retry with the above function and let me know ?

Comment: Why not give postman a chance?